# Can I prevent my (jailbroken) iPhone from retrieving mail between certain hours?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, email, settings

I have a jailbroken iPhone which is set up to retrieve mail every 30 minutes.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening at 3am when I'm trying to sleep?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar as well. Some apps, like Boxcar for twitter updates etc allow you to set a "quiet time" when you don't get notifications, but I haven't found anything similar for Mail (or notifications in general).

Comment: +1 for a good question! Some Android phones sense when they're lying face-down and automatically go into total-silent-mode which is different from when they're lying face-up. Why-oh-why is this missing in iOS? The phone would need to check its position only when it wants to sound an alert.

Comment: For the record, what I've ended up doing is just preventing an alert from sounding when mail is retrieved. i.e. turning off Settings->Sounds->New Mail.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like there is that level of configuration granularity on iOS for the iPhone out of the box (**non-jailbroken**).

One of the common jailbroken apps; 'SBSettings' also don't seem to have a specific setting option for scheduling push times...

One option might be, if you don't want to be disturbed at all is to switch to "Airplane Mode" before you go to sleep. But note this will prevent receiving calls and text messages also.

Or simply turn off "fetch data" (or set it to "manually") before you go to sleep.

**Steps:**

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data > Push = Off | Fetch = "Manually"

Comment: It may also be worth turning notifications off while you're at it, but that doesn't do much about the mail settings.

Comment: +1 for airplane mode. This turns off the cell phone reception too, so it should prevent calls and text messages too!